# Custom REST framework

Tags: java, web-services, rest, servlets

I am trying to understanding jersery REST framework and try to re create my own custom framework for REST.I dont know where to begin with.Can anyone please provide necessary references.

Comment: Why you need your own?

Comment: I want to understand how its implemented.I guess this is not the rite place

Answer (score 1):

Trying to fully understand a JAX-RS framework servlet container like Jersey will probably take you weeks or months, especially if you have to ask where to start. If you want to try, I would start by reading the JAX-RS spec for the version you are looking for. JSR311 is JAX-RS 1.1 and JSR339 for JAX-RS 2.0.

Truth be told, there are several implementations of the JAX-RS spec, and it is a VERY complicated and complex specification. Unless you have a real need (i.e. the existing implementations don't do what you need - which probably means you are doing it wrong), I would just work with what you have. Try our Resteasy if you don't like Jersey, do some googling to find other implementations of the JSR and try them out.